# Exception when endpoint is configured in web.config file

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

I am using wf wcf service and added configured for its control end point in web.config file.
When i call terminate method through workflowcontrol client its thro exception like "The message with To  cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.".
Control end point configuration like this.

At service side-

```
<services>
      <service name="PurchaseOrder">
        <endpoint address=""
        binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="POWorkflowService.IPurchaseOrder" />       
        <endpoint address="wce"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" kind="workflowControlEndpoint" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <workflowControlEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint/>
      </workflowControlEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
```

configuration at client sile is -

```
<client>
           <endpoint address="http://localhost:3650/POService.xamlx/wce" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPurchaseOrderIIS" contract="System.ServiceModel.Activities.IWorkflowInstanceManagement"
                name="IPurchaseOrderControlEndpointISS" />
    </client>
```

I would appreciate to if you help me to find the solution.
Its working fine when i use workflowservice host and add control end point in code.

Answer (score 1):

try setting AddressFilterMode for ServiceBehavior.